# How to code for everchanging number of fields

Tags: mysql

Suppose I am attempting to build an archiving database for a science fiction magazine. I wish to be able to track the contributing authors and illustrators per issue. The problem I run in to is that Issue #1 might have 8 authors and 10 illustrators while #2 has 10 authors and 14 illustrators and #3 has 6 authors and 8 illustrators. I have foreign keys from the Issues table referencing the Authors and Illustrators tables. The problem is that I never know how many of each I will have per issue. I know that the bonehead way is to create 20 columns for tracking potential authors and 20 more for illustrators and filling the table with a BUNCH of nulls, but I know that is not the most efficient. It seems to me there is a way of telling SQL "For record #1 create 8 author columns and 10 illustrator columns and for record #2 10 and 14..." almost like an inset table for each record. I know it's out there, but for the life of me I cannot bring it to mind.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I will be glad to do the reading and coding myself, I have just exhausted all the different keywords I can think of to use in searching for this on my own.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It's a standard many-to-many relationship. You want a mapping table with a `(IssueID, AuthorID)` composite key for each combination, and a similar one for illustrators.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create columns, use a lookup table:

```
contributing_author_id int autoinc primary key
issue_num int foreign key
person_id int foreign key
```

Contributing_author_id is just a surrogate primary key
issue_num points to the issue in question
person_id points to a "person" table in which you keep authors, illustrators, etc with appropriate fields

You could also use the issume_num / person_id field is the primary key, depending on other uses of this table and what your overall standards are.

It is worth nothing that using columns for this is an amazingly bad idea as it makes your SQL and reporting far more work and trouble than it needs to be.  Avoid examples that suggest that.

Answer (score 1):

You could break this into several tables.

```
-- Magazine Issue
MagazineID (auto incrementing int primary key)
IssueID
Date
etc.

-- Person
PersonID (auto incrementing int primary key)
type (illustrator/author)
Name
etc.

-- MagazineIllustrator
MagazineIssue (foreign key to MagazineIssue)
PersonID (foreign key to Person)

--MagazineAuthor
MagazineIssue (foregin key to MagazineIssue)
PersonID (foreign key to Person)
```